# Centos 7 tagged vlan dhcp client

Tags: centos, dhcp, vlan

I'm trying to set up a tagged vlan interface to work with DHCP and I want to make sure I have the client config set correctly.

I have `ifcfg-ens32` set as:

```
DEVICE=ens32
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
```

and I have `ifcfg-ens32.15` set to:

```
DEVICE=ens32.15
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
```

If I attempt to bring the interface up it hangs (hopefully attempting to get a DHCP address) and then bombs out with:

`Error: Connection activation failed.`

and the address does not show when doing an `ip a`

Now, I cannot guarantee the DHCP server is working, so is the above normal behaviour?

If I configure the device to `BOOTPROTO=none` it comes up fine. If I then give it a static address and bring it back up it can ping the router ok so it does look as if the tagging part is working fine.

Comment: The configuration looks correct. Check your DHCP server, switch, router, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the problem ended up being the dhcprelay not being set right on the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config was correct and working, the dhcpforwarder in the ASA it was connected to was set incorrectly. Fixed this and now it's coming up fine and getting an address as required.